# How do I get hold of the current ClaimsPrincipal who's being SignedOut?

Tags: asp.net-core

In my custom **CookieAuthenticationEvents** type I have overriden SigningOut like this, but cannot figure out how to get hold of the Principal who's being signed out. I am trying to do this so I can log who/when is being logged in and out of the app.

```
    public override Task SigningOut(CookieSigningOutContext context)
    {
        // How to get hold of the ClaimsPrincipal?
        return base.SigningOut(context);
    }
```

The SigningOut override however does provide a Principal property like this:

```
    public override Task SigningIn(CookieSigningInContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Signing In SessionID: {context.Principal?.GetClientSessionId()}");
        return base.SigningIn(context);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `context.HttpContext.User`

```cs
public override Task SigningOut(CookieSigningOutContext context)
{
    var user = context.HttpContext.User;

    // log the user

    return base.SigningOut(context);
}
```